Error while extracting Metadata using Java and Apache POI library
I have used maven for dependency handling and Apache POI library to Extract the metadata from Microsoft documents like Word,PowerPoint and Excel.
I was successfully able to extract the MetaData from my Word document and the code is used is as follows:
package org.example;


import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MetaDataExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "/Users/sujalpatel/Desktop/Canteen Reservation PowerApps.docx";  // Replace with the path to your .docx file
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
             XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis)) {

            POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProperties = document.getProperties().getCoreProperties();
            POIXMLProperties.ExtendedProperties extendedProperties = document.getProperties().getExtendedProperties();

            System.out.println("Title: " + coreProperties.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Subject: " + coreProperties.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Creator: " + coreProperties.getCreator());
            System.out.println("Keywords: " + coreProperties.getKeywords());
            System.out.println("Description: " + coreProperties.getDescription());
            System.out.println("Last Modified By: " + coreProperties.getLastModifiedByUser());
            System.out.println("Created: " + coreProperties.getCreated());
            System.out.println("Modified: " + coreProperties.getModified());

            System.out.println("Total Time: " + extendedProperties.getTotalTime());
            System.out.println("Application: " + extendedProperties.getApplication());
            System.out.println("App Version: " + extendedProperties.getAppVersion());

        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



And i am successfully able to get the desired output.
Now i want to extract the metadata properties of the excel file and for which i used the code as below
package org.example;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class ExcelMetaDataExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "/Users/sujalpatel/Desktop/test.xlsx";  // Ensure this is an .xlsx file
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)) {

            POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProperties = workbook.getProperties().getCoreProperties();
            POIXMLProperties.ExtendedProperties extendedProperties = workbook.getProperties().getExtendedProperties();

            // Extract Core Properties
            System.out.println("Title: " + coreProperties.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Subject: " + coreProperties.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Creator: " + coreProperties.getCreator());
            System.out.println("Keywords: " + coreProperties.getKeywords());
            System.out.println("Description: " + coreProperties.getDescription());
            System.out.println("Last Modified By: " + coreProperties.getLastModifiedByUser());
            System.out.println("Created: " + coreProperties.getCreated());
            System.out.println("Modified: " + coreProperties.getModified());

            // Extract Extended Properties
            System.out.println("Total Time: " + extendedProperties.getTotalTime());
            System.out.println("Application: " + extendedProperties.getApplication());
            System.out.println("App Version: " + extendedProperties.getAppVersion());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



I am getting the error for which i am attaching the picture below.
Image for the error
I want to know why exactly i am getting the error if my code works for the one type of file format why not for the other one and I want help that how can I tackle this error.

What combination of Apache POI poi-ooxml and XmlBeans xmlbeans used? Seems that does not fit. If Maven used, then ...<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId> <version>5.2.5</version>... should pull ...<artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId> <version>5.2.0</version>.... But if there is another XmlBeans version in class path, then class loader can get struggled.

<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>       <version>4.1.2</version>
and
<artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>       <version>5.1.1</version>

That does not fit and Maven should not pull this. poi-ooxml 4.1.2 needs poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.2 which needs xmlbeans 3.1.0.
